# How is the word “close” used as an adjective in poems as opposed to “fermé”

Tags: vocabulaire, poésie

In the poem [*Le spectre de la rose*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_nuits_d%27%C3%A9t%C3%A9), set as part of Bizet's *Les nuits d'été*, we find “Soulève ta paupière close”. What's going on here with “close”; is that actually French word, or has the poet borrowed an English word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search in google with "origine of the word closed" returned "Middle English: from Old French clos (as noun and adjective), from Latin clausum ‘enclosure’ and clausus ‘closed’, past participle of claudere ."

The french word seems to be the origine of the english one.

"Close" is the feminine form af the adjective "clos" which describes a closed space or place, or the fact that something is... well... closed. It's often a synonym of "fermé" or "fermée".
The verb associated is "clore".

Answer (score 2):

Any [dictionary](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/close) shows this is a French word, so the English borrowed it to the French, not the other way around.

Being literary, *clos[e]* is more likely to be used in a poem than *fermé*.

Outside set expressions like *espace clos*, *porte close*, *maison close*, *huis clos* *l'incident est clos*, this adjective is rare in spoken French which prefers *fermé[e]* and sometimes *clôturé*.

Almost nobody would say *je n'ai pas pu faire les course, le magasin était clos*, or *est-ce que la fenêtre est bien close ?*

Similarily, the verb *clore* being quite irregular is also only used in limited tenses and persons (e.g. *vous closez* is very rare). The regular *clôturer* (which is derived from *clore* through *clôture*) being preferred along with *fermer*.

Comment: The one attempt I made to look it up failed. Obviously, an inadequate attempt.

Comment: *«Espace clos»* is fairly common. Among the closely related words, one could think of [*«enclos»*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclos), [*«clôture»*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cl%C3%B4ture), and [*«cloître»*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clo%C3%AEtre). Further away in the family, we could think of [*«claustrophobie»*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claustrophobie).

Comment: @Feelew My comment was about the adjective. Yes, *espace clos* and other set expressions like *porte close*, *maison close*, *l'incident est clos* are still used, but otherwise, *clos* is rare and often formal. Nobody would say *je n'ai pas pu faire les course, le magasin était clos*, or *est-ce que la fenêtre est bien close ?*

Comment: Qqs exemples bien vivants: la discussion est close, la réunion est close, l'incident est clos, le débat est clos. Et un exemple à usage plus restreint, mais encore actuel, dans le domaine des mathématiques: un corps (algébriquement, intégralement, quadratiquement) clos.

Comment: @Feelew, Beaucoup sont des expressions toutes faites. J'ai déjà cité *l'incident est clos*. Pour clarifier mon propos, je n'ai pas écrit que *clos* n'était pas utilisé mais qu'il était rare en français parlé courant et qu'on lui préférait d'autres adjectifs. *Clos/close* sont toujours bien présents en Français recherché et/ou écrit.

Answer (score 1):

The poet has chosen to use the fairly uncommon word "close" for the sake of the rhyme with "rose":

Soulève ta paupière close

Qu'effleure un songe virginal;

Je suis le spectre d'une rose

Que tu portais hier au bal.